# what is the difference in between the following two lines in opencv for images

Tags: c++, opencv, vector

```
vector<Mat> images;
vector<int> labels;
```

I assume that  `Mat` is a structure for images and `int` is a datatype. But what is `vector`?
Is it a array of two dimension? Please clear my doubt thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

In C++, [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) is a sequence container that encapsulates **dynamic size arrays**. It's a **`1`-dimension array**, whose elements are stored contiguously.

- For `vector<Mat> images;`, `images` is declared to be a `1`-dimension array, whose elements are [**`cv::Mat`**](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat)s.

  To define a `2`-dimension array of such elements, you can use `vector<vector<Mat>> images_2d;`.
- For `vector<int> labels;`, `labels` is declared to be a `1`-dimension array, whose elements are `int`s.

  To define a `2`-dimension array of such elements, you can use `vector<vector<int>> labels_2d;`.

Answer (score 0):

`vector<int> labels` means a vector of labels. So, whenever you want to insert an element in this vector, you it by `label.push_back(elementToBeInserted);`.

And whenever you want to access  the elements present in this vector, you can do the following:

```
for(int i=0; i<labels.size(); i++)
{
    int element = labels[i];
    cout<<Element: <<element;

}
```

And the similar description is applicable for `vector<Mat> images;`. One more thing is that `Mat` represents `Matrix` and images are stored as Matrices.

**PS:** `vector< vector<int> >labels;` will represent a 2D vector

Comment: is vector similar to array if yes then what is diff

Comment: without going into programming details, i would say that they are similar but the major difference is that in case of `vectors` you don't need to specify the size. Whenever you want to insert an element, you do it by `label.push_back()` and it is stored in the next available location. Please upvote/accept my answer also if it was useful to you.